# trouble with getting tax rate name in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Hi currently i want to get the name of the tax rate in woocommerce. I there any way to get the value that is circled in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyGAH.png

My current code:

```
$items = $order->get_items();
        $lineItem = array();
        $productInfo = $orderInfo = array();
        $order_items = array();
        if ($items) foreach ($items as $item_key => $item_value) {
            $_tax = new WC_Tax();
            $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item_value );
            $product_tax_class = $_product->get_tax_class();
            $tax_class = $item_value['tax_class'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the [`WC_Tax()->find_rates()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Tax.html#199-230) method. It takes an array as an argument, which in your case would be `array( 'country' => 'NO' )` and returns an array of matching tax rates. One of the keys of this array is `label` which contains the name of the tax rate.

```
$tax = new WC_Tax();
$country_code = 'NO'; // or populate from order to get applicable rates
$rates = $tax->find_rates( array( 'country' => $country_code ) );
foreach( $rates as $rate ){
    $tax_rate_name = $rate['label'];
}
```

To find the applicable tax rates for a specific order, populate the array for `find_rates()` with values from the shipping/billing address on the order.

Comment: How I get the tax rate id?

Comment: I think you can use http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_taxget_rates_for_tax_class/